# Get SQL file for specific migration in Entity Framework 6 C#

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

In Entity Framework 6, I need to get the SQL script for specific migration file and I already updated the database. I found that in `update-database` command I can add script parameter to export the migration to SQL, but I already updated the database. I found in Entity Framework Core, a command called `Script-Migration` with script name as an argument. Is there any similar command in Entity framework?

I also tried the suggestion "[Update database command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pvcJ.png)", but I got an empty SQL file.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you could generate the migration-SQL as follows:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: <pointFromWichYouWantToStartWithGeneration> -TargetMigration: <pointWhereToEndWithGeneration>
```

To create a script for all migrations execute the following:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

Instead of applying the changes to database it will generate a SQL script file. Therefore you could generate a SQL Script even if the migration was already applied to the database.

Here you could find some more information about it - [Entity Framework Code First Migrations - Getting a SQL Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_6).

> Run the `Update-Database` command but this time specify the `–Script` flag so that changes are written to a script rather than applied. We’ll also specify a source and target migration to generate the script for.

Comment: I tried the above, and it doesn't work .. i got message that "Target database is already at version " & empty sql file

Comment: Hm, I tried it and it works like expected. I use EF 6.2. Have you set a start and end migration? If you only use `Update-Database -Script` it will not work because EF does not know where to start with generation.

Comment: it is working for me when i removed the targetmigration part and kept as source migration only, in this case i got the SQL file. Thanks

Comment: Getting the same issue as @MohamedAbdeen. Using the full database script generation and extracting the required parts worked for me though.

Comment: You are a life saver! I was searching for over an hour and although my problem was not close to the original question i got what i wanted!

Answer (score 16):

If you're now in .net core, use

```
Script-Migration -From <PreviousMigration> -To <LastMigration>
```

If you don't execute the last migration, you can run

```
Script-Migration -From <PreviousMigration>
```

Don't include the date/times preceeding the migration name.
For example if the migration name in the database is: `20210209184835_add-parent-id-to-contract`, then run the following in the package manager

```
Script-Migration -From add-parent-id-to-contract
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to generate -Script for migration N, you specify -SourceMigration N-1 (previous migration) and -TargetMigration N

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command from Package manager console. It will generate a temporary file and will open it in VS:

```
Script-Migration
```

Answer (score 0):

The following generates a SQL script from the given migration to the latest migration using VS > Package Manager Console (Use the name of the migration before the last one to get only the latest migration script).

```
Script-Migration <PreviousMigrationName>
```

If have only one migration file, the following generates a SQL script from a blank database to the latest migration:

```
Script-Migration
```