# Error when ManyToMany relation Code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i have some trouble with Many To Many relation with an associated table on Entity-Framework V6.
I use MySql as database and I already get always the same error.

I tried many tuto on youtube, stackoverflow, entityframeworktutorial, entityframework documentation but i have always the same error when i try to make a Many To Many relation.

I use .NET 4.7.2 Framework, MySQL 5.7.24, Entity Framework 6, MySql Connector 8.0.15, MySql.Data 6.10.8.0, MySQl.Data.Entity.EF6 6.10.8.0

This is my first Entity :

```
[Table("course")]
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [Column("idcourse")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Students { get; set; }
}
```

My second entity :

```
[Table("student")]
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [Column("idstudent")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Important - virtual
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

And my associted table :

```
[Table("student_course")]
public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key]
    [Column("idstudent_course")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("idstudent")]
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Column("idcourse")]
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    [Column("coursescore")]
    public int CourseScore { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

When i launc an add-migration [name] no problem. But when i try to do an update-database Visual Studio put me this error :The input string format is incorrect. (translate because im french and my IDE is in french)

Someone have a solution?
Thank !

Comment: some more info for the exception ? Inner Exception maybe, stack trace or any sql query part ? this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552550/get-sql-file-for-specific-migration-in-entity-framework-6-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MySQL but the general approach to solving runtime issues like this is to use an profiler against the SQL database to extract the SQL that EF is trying to run, then inspect and execute that query manually against the database to hopefully reveal what column EF is getting mixed up on.

Are you using any other configuration for the relationship between student and course? One thing to check would be to check any existing many to many mapping, or add it if it doesn't exist. EF can auto-map many-to-many, but AFAIK it expects certain conventions such as expecting the joining table to have a composite key.

You could try getting rid of the extra PK:

```
[Table("student_course")]
public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key, Column("idstudent", Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("idcourse", Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Column("coursescore")]
    public int CourseScore { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Normally EF expects to manage the joining table automatically in a many-to-many where you don't even declare the joining entity. This would expect the Student to have a collection of Courses, and the Course to have a collection of Student. The downside of this, is that you would lose the availability of any extra info on the joining entity. (CourseScore) With the joining entity, it becomes a 1-to-many-to-1 as far as EF's mapping is concerned, so you may need to explicitly map out the relationship through the joining table. (Either via an EntityTypeConfiguration, or OnModelCreating event.

I.e.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>.HasMany(x => x.Courses).WithRequired(x => x.Student);
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>.HasMany(x => x.Students).WithRequired(x => x.Course);
```

This ensures that EF sets up the relationship between Student/Course and the StudentCourse as a 1-to-many each way.

Comment: my migration keep tell me the same error i dont know why i cant updatemy database to get the good schema :(