# Retrieve automatic migration fail details

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, database-migration

In my ASP.NET Entity Framework 6 project I added a new Model and Controller.
I have automatic migration enabled but allowed data loss disabled.

When I ran the application after these changes the new table was actually created into the db, but the application told me:

> Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss

Without any other detail. As read in other questions I tried to issue:

```
Database-Update -Script
```

to get the "differences" but nothing happened, just the same error message.
I really don't want to force the update unless I'm sure what it's going to do.

What should I do in order to retrieve the content of the current migration?
I tried to look into the dbo.__MigrationHistory table but the Model field contains binary data.

### UPDATE

I was able to decode the Model field using [this](https://github.com/andreydil/EfMigrationModelDecoder) method, but the edmx file contains just the whole diagram of the db, not the actual commands the the migration would issue.

Furthermore, even if add the `-Verbose` flag as suggested by the tool itself:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'MyProject'.
Using NuGet project 'MyProject'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
```

It does not show the SQL statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is displayed because you probably made some change to your model that results in a DROP command (e.g. removing property).

To see the script for that specific migration, i.e. the update between the latest migration and the one before it, you can use the following command:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: <migrationBeforeTheLastOne> -TargetMigration: <lastMigration>
```

as stated in [ChW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49552770/10380786).

Comment: I tried to use that command, but it says I can only use explicit migrations for both Source and Target parameters.

Comment: To be sure, I went back to the previous backup and add again the code (Model and Controller). I noticed that the first time the application runs it applies the migration nicely and add the new table to the db. Then if I run again the application (without *any* change) it shows the error about data loss.

Comment: Found my problem: it was missing the `public DbSet<>` in the context. Anyway, I confirm I cannot see the SQL statements for automatic migrations.