# Get SQL file for specific migration in Entity Framework Core C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am using visual studio, EF Core
I have for example Migration files

for example `20210314142045_RemoveCitizenShip3.cs` as
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

```
namespace CertificateSystem.DB.DB.Migrations
{
    public partial class RemoveCitizenShip3 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "CitizenShip",
                schema: "CertificateSystem",
                table: "CommercialEntity");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "CitizenShip",
                schema: "CertificateSystem",
                table: "CommercialEntity",
                nullable: true);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to take my project and publish it to production I understand that Migrations Is not a good way to work with on a production
I think the best way to update my database it is to make a Migration on the developing version and create a SQL out of it and execute the SQL on the production

My problem is how do I create a SQL file from a Migration file?

I have read that  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552550/get-sql-file-for-specific-migration-in-entity-framework-6-c-sharp`

And I saw that Script-Migration -From X -to Y do some work but If I want to do it on specific file? How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by specific file? Do you mean from the first migration to that file(`-to RemoveCitizenShip3`), or from that file to the latest migration(`-from RemoveCitizenShip3`)?

Comment: I mean from last state of the database to the next migration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
Script-Migration -From <PreviousMigration> -To <LastMigration>
```

In your case,

```
Script-Migration 20180904195021_InitialCreate
```

The above example creates a script for all migrations after the InitialCreate migration, using the migration ID. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#script-migration)
And if you're using .net core CLI tools,

```
dotnet ef migrations script 20180904195021_InitialCreate
```

Always follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script)

Comment: Sometimes its create to me a empty script do you know why?