# Get Empty SQL file for specific migration in Entity Framework Core C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using visual studio, EF Core

I want to take my project and publish it to production I understand that Migrations Is not a good way to work with on a production I think the best way to update my database it is to make a Migration on the developing version and create a SQL out of it and execute the SQL on the production

I have open this question : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66966860/get-sql-file-for-specific-migration-in-entity-framework-core-c-sharp`

But some of the scripts return empty I have no idea why...

for example :

I have the next file :  `20210314131832_RemoveCitizenShip2.cs`
with the next code :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

    namespace CertificateSystem.DB.DB.Migrations
    {
        public partial class RemoveCitizenShip2 : Migration
        {
            protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
            {
                migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                    name: "CitizenShip",
                    schema: "CertificateSystem",
                    table: "CommercialEntity");
            }
    
            protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
            {
                migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                    name: "CitizenShip",
                    schema: "CertificateSystem",
                    table: "CommercialEntity",
                    nullable: true);
            }
        }
    }
```

execute : Script-Migration 20210314131832_RemoveCitizenShip2 just work fine

and return the next SQL Script :

```
ALTER TABLE [CertificateSystem].[CommercialEntity] ADD [CitizenShip] int NULL;

GO

INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20210314132027_AddBackCitizenShip2', N'2.2.4-servicing-10062');

GO

DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[CertificateSystem].[CommercialEntity]') AND [c].[name] = N'CitizenShip');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [CertificateSystem].[CommercialEntity] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [CertificateSystem].[CommercialEntity] DROP COLUMN [CitizenShip];

GO

INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20210314142045_RemoveCitizenShip3', N'2.2.4-servicing-10062');

GO
```

I also have the next file : 20210406095255_ChangeUidToInt.cs

with the code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace OnlineShvaConnection.DB.Db.Migrations
{
    public partial class ChangeUidToInt : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
                name: "Id",
                schema: "OnlineShvaConnection",
                table: "LogMessages",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(Guid))
                .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
                name: "Id",
                schema: "OnlineShvaConnection",
                table: "LogMessages",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(long))
                .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

and it return a empty SQL file on the next command line :

Script-Migration 20210406095255_ChangeUidToInt

I have no idea why it can happen...

Comment: you can try `Script-Migration -Idempotent`, it applies the missing migrations. This is useful if you don't exactly know what the last migration applied to the database was. you can also try with options `-from` and `-to`