# ASP.NET MVC - How to fix EF migration history differences on local and production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses EF migrations. Usually when I make changes to the model in local development, I create new migration, and then to apply the changes in production I generate a script with the modifications and apply it to the production server db.
I have been doing this for months, and apparently it worked ok, so I assumed that both databases were synced (i.e. the migrationHistory table was the same in both databases).

But now I have just realised that the contents of the `__MigrationHistory` table are different in local and server: in local there is one migration that does not exist in server (note: its not the last migration, its one from months ago). So let's say in local I have these migrations applied (as shown in migrationHistory table):

```
migration 1
migration 2
migration 3
migration 4
```

but in server, I don't have migration 2.

I don't understand how this happened: I though EF would not allow this and it should have throw an error when I tried to apply migration 3 in server, but apparently it did not...

So the question is: how can I fix this now?

My first idea is to

1. modify local model to remove the changes on the offending migration
2. delete migration file
3. delete local database
4. recreate local database with update-database
5. re-do changes to the model
6. create new migration
7. update db to apply new migration
8. generate script with the changes and apply it to the production db

If I am right, with this both databases will be synced? Or what would be the correct way to fix all this?

Comment: Why generate a script in the first place? Why not just run the migrations against production the same as you did for local? I doubt your idea would work because you’d get into clashes with your “new” migration. You’d end up trying to recreate something that has already been done and that will throw an error. What does the missing migration look like? Could it potentially be one that can be re ran? If not, you may have to rollback all migrations and re run them afterwards again. But next time, just run the migration against your production database.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker Visual Studio is not installed on server.. how can I run migrations there?

Comment: Maybe this is too simple to work, but have you tried generating the script for only migration 2 and applying it to production?  EF lets you do that (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552550/get-sql-file-for-specific-migration-in-entity-framework-6-c-sharp)

Comment: Just be careful and review the script first if you decide to try that since it may delete production data if it's dropping tables or anything like that.

Comment: @patsy2k - you don’t need Visual Studio. Migrations are a dotnet command and you can run it via command line